# How to resolve a service's name to IP from a kubernetes node's perspective?

Tags: dns, kubernetes, kube-dns

I have a kubernetes cluster running on GCE.

I created a setup in which I have 2 *pods* `glusterfs-server-1` and `glusterfs-server-2` that are my gluster server.

The 2 `glusterfsd` daemon correctly communicate and I am able to create replicated volumes, write files to them and see the files correctly replicated on both pods.

I also have 1 *service* called `glusterfs-server` that automatically balances the traffic between my 2 glusterfs pods.

From inside another pod, I can issue `mount -t glusterfs glusterfs-server:/myvolume /mnt/myvolume` and everything works perfectly.

Now, what I really want is being able to use the `glusterfs` volume type inside my .yaml files when creating a container:

`...truncated...
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: myvolume
          glusterfs:
            endpoints: glusterfs-server
            path: myvolume
...truncated...`

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I was able to find out why it doesn't work:

When connecting directly to a kubernetes *node*, issuing a `mount -t glusterfs glusterfs-server:/myvolume /mnt/myvolume` does not work, this is because from my node's perspective `glusterfs-server` does not resolve to any IP address. (That is `getent hosts glusterfs-server` returns nothing)

And also, due to how glusterfs works, even directly using the service's IP will fail as glusterfs will still eventually try to resolve the name `glusterfs-server` (and fail).

Now, just for fun and to validate that this is the issue, I edited my node's `resolv.conf` (by putting my kube-dns IP address and search domains) so that it would correctly resolve my pods and services ip addresses. I then was finally able to successfully issue `mount -t glusterfs glusterfs-server:/myvolume /mnt/myvolume` on the node. I was then also able to create a pod using a glusterfs volume (using the PodSpec above).

Now, I'm fairly certain modifying my node's `resolv.conf` is a terrible idea: kubernetes having the notion of namespaces, if 2 services in 2 different namespaces share the same name (say, glusterfs-service), a `getent hosts glusterfs-service` would resolve to 2 different IPs living in 2 different namespaces.

So my question is:

*What can I do for my node to be able to resolve my pods/services IP addresses?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify `resolv.conf` and use the full service names to avoid collisions. Usually are like this: `service_name.default.svc.cluster.local` and `service_name.kube-system.svc.cluster.local` or whatever namespace is named.

Comment: I originally didn't want to modify the nodes' resolv.conf because I assumed that since it wasn't already done by default, there probably was a good reason. I found out this is simply because it's too complicated to configure resolv.conf on many different distribution: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/8735.